Can enums share concrete methods to avoid repetition?
I use value objects that have a [unit] property that is a enum.
My enums implement an interface to permit conversion between units (cm to m, kg to g, etc...)
Like this :
class Height {
  final double value;
  final DistanceUnit unit;
  
  const Height({required this.value, this.unit = DistanceUnit.cm});
}

// Directly implementing Enum so that only enums can implement this ; important for another method.
abstract interface class Convertible implements Enum {
  final double factor;

  Convertible({required this.factor});

  double getConversionFactor(covariant Convertible from, covariant Convertible to);
}

enum DistanceUnit implements Convertible {
  cm(factor: 1/100),
  m(factor: 1);
  
  @override
  final double factor;
  
  const DistanceUnit({required this.factor});
  
  @override
  double getConversionFactor(covariant Convertible from, covariant Convertible to) {
    return from.factor / to.factor;
  }
}

This work very well but as I have many units (area, distance, volume, time, mass...) it becomes very verbose and repetitive. The getConversionFactor() method is always the same... So we are far away from the DRY advice !
I know enums inherit from Enum and cannot extend another class. But is there another way to prevent this and optimize my code ?

I would prefer creating extension on entity and use the minimal unit in entity's field(dataType)

I can't get the full case inside my head but if are looking for removing the reddest for getConversionFactor just you can use mixin as below
class Height {
final double value;
final DistanceUnit unit;

const Height({required this.value, this.unit = DistanceUnit.cm});
}
// Directly implementing Enum so that only enums can implement this ; important for another method.
abstract interface class Convertible implements Enum {
final double factor;

Convertible({required this.factor});


}

enum DistanceUnit  with Conver implements Convertible{
cm(factor: 1/100),
m(factor: 1);

@override
final double factor;

const DistanceUnit({required this.factor});
}
mixin Conver  {
double getConversionFactor(covariant Convertible from, covariant Convertible to) {
 return from.factor / to.factor;
}
}

I think you may try another way by using map (data structure)
you can consider this solution

I would prefer extension for this.
class MyModel {
  const MyModel(this.valueInCM);

  ///* in minimum  unite, e.g for your domain level,
  /// we can consider from cm, if needed you goes down too
  final double valueInCM;
}

extension MyModelExt on MyModel {
  double get toMeter => valueInCM / 100;
  double get toKM => valueInCM / 1000;
}

Also you can checkout Duration class in dart.

Thank you for your answers about mixins, I have tried it before posting yesterday but I think I was wrong in the way I managed inheritance.
The way it works without breaking the global logic :
mixin ConvertibleImplementor implements Convertible {
    @override
    double getConversionFactor(Convertible from, Convertible to) {
        return from.factor / to.factor;
    }
    
    @override
    double getConversionFactorFrom(Convertible from) => this.getConversionFactor(from, this);
    
    @override
    double getConversionFactorTo(Convertible to) => this.getConversionFactor(this, to);
}

enum TimeUnit with ConvertibleImplementor {
    ms(factor: 1/(24*60*60*1000)),
    s(factor: 1/(24*60*60)),
    min(factor: 1/(24*60)),
    h(factor: 1/24),
    day(factor: 1),
    week(factor: 7),
    month(factor: 30.5),
    year(factor: 365);
    
    @override
    final double factor;
    
    const TimeUnit({required this.factor});
}

